# What's the Java equivalent for PHP's password_hash and password_verify?

Tags: java, php

I have a MySQL database where **one** column is used to store password.

It is implemented in PHP, using `password_hash()` to salt and hash the original password on registering, and retrieving the MySQL row of the logging-in user and then `password_verify()` its password.

But I need to move it in Java. So are there Java equivalents for `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`?

Comment: I don't think there is anything directly compatible (perhaps you could use something from [quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/)).

Comment: You could try using [this implementation](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) of BCrypt.

Comment: What algorithm is `password_hash` using?

Comment: @BoristheSpider `BCRYPT` (blowfish) with apparently different cycles count

Comment: @Xenos  you need to work out the number of rounds used, then simply use [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the implementation by mindrot:
https://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/

To replicate the `password_hash` you can use:

```
String hash = BCrypt.hashpw("password");
```

And to replicate `password_verify` use:

```
boolean s = BCrypt.checkpw("password", hash);
```

This works great with my Laravel project.

I made a few tweaks to the lib, to allow the use of a random salt, instead of passing a new one each time you call `hashpw` method, and to support multiple versions of salt.

You can find it here: https://github.com/promatik/jBCrypt

Comment: Do not forget to add the repo to gradle, i.e. *implementation "org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4"*

Comment: I have an hash starting with "$2y" and I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt revision, do you know why? Thanks

Comment: Finally I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709857/hash-a-password-with-2y-in-java
A string replacement of $2y to $2a is needed

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/at.favre.lib/bcrypt

Code example:

```
import at.favre.lib.crypto.bcrypt.*;
import at.favre.lib.bytes.Bytes;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
...
String pw = "candidate_password";
String hash = "<hash from users table>";
BCrypt.Result result = BCrypt.verifyer(BCrypt.Version.VERSION_2Y)
                    .verifyStrict(pw.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), hash.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            if (result.verified) {
                System.out.println(" It matches");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" It does not match");
            }
...
```