# Hash a password with $2y$ in java

Tags: java, bcrypt

i am having issues with hashing passwords in java so when i try to log in and write my password i want to get that written password hash it using $2y$ as the same format in my database because that it what the FOSBundle is using as encryption methode the BCrypt but instead i get a hashed password which starts with $2a$ instead of $2y$ so i can't compare them is there anyway to change that $2a$ hash into $2y$ hash ?

My function :

```
public void CheckLogin(String username,String password) throws SQLException{

  String requete = "Select * from user WHERE username ='"+username+"';";   
  ste = con.createStatement();
  res = ste.executeQuery(requete);

  while(res.next()) {
    if (res.getString(2).equals(username)) { 
      System.out.println("Password FOS ="+res.getString(8));

      String hashed2 = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(12));
      hashed2 = "$2y$" + hashed2.substring(4);
      System.out.println("HASHED PASSWORD =" + hashed2);

      if (BCrypt.checkpw(res.getString(8),hashed2)) {
        System.out.println("It matches"); 
      } else {
        System.out.println("It does not match");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

he can't find the user i am looking for because the hashed password i passed to him " hashed2 " is not the same in my database because in my database it stars with $2y$ and this hash methode give a $2a$ hashed password

Comment: If you're concerned about security, the first thing you should do is learn about SQL injection attacks, and use prepared statements instead of concatenating parameters. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: yes sure i totally agree with you but i just want to get the result first then i will use prepared statements but for the moment i am just testing

Comment: @rustyx is there anyway to make a hashed password wich starts with $2y$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [BCrypt wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Versioning_History) the prefix $2a$, $2y$ and $2b$ are used to store the algorithm version. Although $2y$ fixed a bug in previous implementation this fix seems to be limited to PHP:

> In June 2011, a bug was discovered in crypt_blowfish, a PHP implementation of BCrypt.
>
> ...
>
> Nobody else, including canonical OpenBSD, adopted the idea of 2x/2y.
>   This version marker change was limited to crypt_blowfish.

Since it looks like you are using JBCrypt you will always get $2a$ version. Latest version 0.4 definitely uses it.

You can try comparing the hashed password without the version prefix. I never had to compare PHP and Java BCrypt implementation so I've no idea if this will work. In your code you can do following:

```
// JBCrypt requires version $2a, change the prefix
String hashed2 = "$2a" + res.getString(8).substring(3);
if (BCrypt.checkpw(password, hashed2)) {
  System.out.println("It matches"); 
}
```

Comment: i looked in the internet and i decrypted the password in the database with the written one using Bcrypt and it worked fine so just now i can't find how to do that in code with java

Comment: @AOUADISlim try the stupid `substring` approach, added the code to my answer.  This `$2a` is hardcoded in JBCrypt so this will not change the hash real value.

Comment: i used ur code but it didn't work it a invalid salt revision error when i compare using BCrypt.checkpw(res.getString(8),hashed2)

Comment: @AOUADISlim kindly show all your code. I have no idea why are you generating this new salt with `BCrypt.gensalt()` at the beginning. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: there you go i put my function

Comment: @AOUADISlim you are not supposed to generate new password with new salt every single time. You need to compare the plain text `password` to `hashed2`. I fixed your code to use `checkpw` correctly

Comment: Ohh ! Thanks a lot man i really appreciate that u just saved me haha thanks again !

Comment: A new implementation of the Bcrypt should be this one: https://github.com/patrickfav/bcrypt

Comment: Also, consider using a new implementation of the jBcrypt library as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448434/1977778